# Why am I getting ORA-06592: CASE not found while executing CASE statement in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following CASE in PL/SQL

```
        CASE
            WHEN v_line_item.custom_segment = 'CND1' THEN
                v_current_col := v_col_lcy_tps;
            WHEN v_line_item.custom_segment = 'CND2' THEN
                v_current_col := v_col_lcy_ib;
            WHEN v_line_item.custom_segment = 'CND3' THEN
                v_current_col := v_col_lcy_gm;
            WHEN v_line_item.custom_segment = 'CND4' THEN
                v_current_col := v_col_lcy_pb;
            WHEN v_line_item.custom_segment = 'CND5' THEN
                v_current_col := v_col_lcy_bb;
        END CASE;
```

The code compiles fine, but when I execute to stored proc I get the following error:

> ORA-06592: CASE not found while executing CASE statement

So when I remove the CASE; the stored proc won't compile. The only Examples I can get my hands on, uses the CASE in a select statement, I don't want to use it in select statement, I want to set my variable without having a bunch of IF THEN ELSE statements.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you use a `CASE` statement - the listings under the `CASE` - must match all conditions that  you might encounter - either explicitly as you have done by using

```
WHEN v_line_item.custom_segment = 'CND1' THEN
            v_current_col := v_col_lcy_tps;
WHEN v_line_item.custom_segment = 'CND2' THEN
```

or by using the `ELSE` clause.

Your code is hitting a situation  where `v_line_item.custom_segment` doesn't match any of the given `CASE` scenarios, hence Oracle raises this exception.

You could add a catch-all condition

```
ELSE
   -- do some work here, raise an exception or log it.
```

so that it matches all conditions.

Further reading:

- [What you must know about CASE in PL/SQL](http://awads.net/wp/2007/07/25/what-you-ought-to-know-about-case-in-oracle-plsql/)
- [Oracle Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm) on CASE

Answer (score 1):

Old thread I know, but wouldn't you just write it like this?

```
v_current_col :=
    case v_line_item.custom_segment
        when 'CND1' then v_col_lcy_tps
        when 'CND2' then v_col_lcy_ib
        when 'CND3' then v_col_lcy_gm
        when 'CND4' then v_col_lcy_pb
        when 'CND5' then v_col_lcy_bb
    end;
```

It's more concise and readable and it won't give an ORA-06592 error.

Comment: not releated to the problem.

Comment: It kind of is. For one thing, it avoids the ORA-06592 error reported in the question.